# R-Model is failing with below error in Azure Data Bricks, any one faced this issue earlier. It ran well till last week

Tags: r, scala, databricks, azure-databricks

Below is the error message

Error in predict.xgb.Booster(model, modelling_matrix, ntreelimit = model[["bestInd"]]) : Error in predict.xgb.Booster(model, modelling_matrix, ntreelimit = model[["bestInd"]]) : 
  [14:38:58] amalgamation/../src/learner.cc:506: Check failed: mparam_.num_feature != 0 (0 vs. 0) : 0 feature is supplied.  Are you using raw Booster interface?
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) /databricks/spark/R/lib/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so(dmlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()+0x64) [0x7ffaa0a21374]
  [bt] (1) /databricks/spark/R/lib/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so(xgboost::LearnerConfiguration::ConfigureNumFeatures()+0xf0) [0x7ffaa0ac1570]
  [bt] (2) /databricks/spark/R/lib/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so(xgboost::LearnerConfiguration::Configure()+0x356) [0x7ffaa0b1c896]
  [bt] (3) /databricks/spark/R/lib/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so(xgboost::LearnerImpl::Predict(std::shared_ptr, bool, xgboost::HostDeviceVector*, unsigned int, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool)+0x7d) [0x7ffaa0ac01fd]
  [bt] (4) /databricks/spark/R/lib/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so(XGBoosterPredict+0xf0) [0x7ffaa0a357b0]
  [bt] (5) /databricks/spark/R/lib/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so(XGBoosterPredict_R+0x89) [0x7ffaa0a1d339]
  [bt] (6
Error in predict.xgb.Booster(model, modelling_matrix, ntreelimit = model[["bestInd"]]) : 
  [14:38:58] amalgamation/../src/learner.cc:506: Check failed: mparam_.num_feature != 0 (0 vs. 0) : 0 feature is supplied.  Are you using raw Booster interface?
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) /databricks/spark/R/lib/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so(dmlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()+0x64) [0x7ffaa0a21374]
  [bt] (1) /databricks/spark/R/lib/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so(xgboost::LearnerConfiguration::ConfigureNumFeatures()+0xf0) [0x7ffaa0ac1570]
  [bt] (2) /databricks/spark/R/lib/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so(xgboost::LearnerConfiguration::Configure()+0x356) [0x7ffaa0b1c896]
  [bt] (3) /databricks/spark/R/lib/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so(xgboost::LearnerImpl::Predict(std::shared_ptr, bool, xgboost::HostDeviceVector*, unsigned int, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool)+0x7d) [0x7ffaa0ac01fd]
  [bt] (4) /databricks/spark/R/lib/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so(XGBoosterPredict+0xf0) [0x7ffaa0a357b0]
  [bt] (5) /databricks/spark/R/lib/xgboost/libs/xgboost.so(XGBoosterPredict_R+0x89) [0x7ffaa0a1d339]
  [bt] (6